# ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\DINESH\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2

Tags: android, c, batch-file

if i am click the android sdk and avd manager in my android studio beta i got the following errors, so anyone please answer me how to resolve this problem..,

ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\DINESH\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified: Cannot run program "C:\Users\DINESH\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: _The system cannot find the file specified_ It seems pretty clear